# is there something wrong in my code? i am not receiving the desired output

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT
  CASE
   WHEN (A = B) AND (B = C) THEN 'Equilateral'
   WHEN (A = B) OR (B = C) OR (A = C) THEN 'Isosceles' 
   WHEN ((A+B) < C) OR ((A+C) < B) OR ((C+B) < A)  THEN 'Not A Triangle'
   ELSE 'Scalene'
  END 
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

i am checking the type of triangle if length of the sides are given as A, B, C in the table TRIANGLES.

Comment: What output did you expect? What output did you get instead? What's the input data?

Comment: you can have A = B, but A+B < C, getting `Isosceles` when expected `Not A Triangle`, switch the last two when conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think you SQL should be like this.
You should check Not A Triangle condition first, and you should change `<` operator to `<=` as well. And I suggest you should select A, B, C as well to make it more readable.

```sql
 SELECT A, B, C,
  CASE
   WHEN ((A+B) <= C) OR ((A+C) <= B) OR ((C+B) <= A)  THEN 'Not A Triangle'
   WHEN (A = B) AND (B = C) THEN 'Equilateral'
   WHEN (A = B) OR (B = C) OR (A = C) THEN 'Isosceles' 
   ELSE 'Scalene'
  END 
FROM TRIANGLES;
```